# Spring Tool Suite, "Content Assist Error" while accessing class memebers

Tags: java, spring-tool-suite, content-assist, code-intelligence

Most of the times here is the error message displayed for content assist while accessing class members.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By following the recommended solution in the error message, here is how it is been solved.

[image]